# distinguish in between div's when all the div has same classname

Tags: javascript

I have 5 div’s containing same classname in html file and I cannot change anything on that html file and I want to add some onload event through javascript only on a div(and on which div I want to add this event is dynamic that is based on some previous if condition) and other div’s should remain untouched?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide the code of your tries? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just add an id attribute to each div

Comment: Can you post your HTML code with which you are dealing this problem? and what solution you have tried so far? without knowing the code it is very hard to help you out.

Comment: try with this `$( "div.classname" ).eq(1)`, where `1` or other is the div number based on your condition

Comment: Are `div`s you want to add events on are added dynamically? Please explain your code properly and if possible share some sample code supporting explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Going by whatever you have stated in your question, here is a small snippet that could give you an idea

```
window.onload = function () {
    var _index = // Index of the div you want to access
    var _divHandle = document.querySelectorAll(".div-class-name")[_index];
    // Do what you want with _divHandle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

This returns an array of all the elements with the class name specified. You would use it like this:

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
var decision = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); //Simulating a random scenario to give us 1 to 5, being which div we will change.

elems[decision].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

```html
<div class="myClass">One</div>
<div class="myClass">Two</div>
<div class="myClass">Three</div>
<div class="myClass">Four</div>
<div class="myClass">Five</div>
```